# SQL Azure & VB.NET ?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I signed up for a free 30 of Azure. I logged in, created a database. I am able to connect (=Test Connectivity). But that's it. I don't see anyway to create tables, etc. Also how can I connect this db to vb.net (I am using vs.net 2010)?

Answer (score 4):

To point SSMS at the DB, simply specify the server and user name. The server name was assigned when you created the SQL Azure database "server" and has a name like .database.windows.net.

Alternatively, you can select the database you want to work with and click on "manage" in teh toolbar along the top. This will launch the "Microsoft Database Manager for SQL Azure". It used to be called "project Houston" and is essentially a silverlight app that lets you perform most basic tasks against SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [visual studio tools and training kit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrick_butler_monterde/archive/2010/06/08/windows-azure-vs-tools-1-2-and-training-kit-released.aspx) from Microsoft. I beleive you will find your answers there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio](http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2009/11/11/Connecting-to-SQL-Azure-with-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2008-R2.aspx)